# Group newly made parameter values in linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to group newly made key values but i'm not getting it to work.

This is the code

```
Dim result = From v In dc.tbl_voertuigs
             Join tv In dc.tbl_type_voertuigs On tv.pk_type_voertuig Equals v.fk_type_voertuig
             Join tbc In dc.tbl_tebehalencertificaats On tbc.pk_tebehalencertificaat Equals v.fk_tebehalencertificaat
             Where tbc.naam_certificaat = subquery2
             Select New Voertuig With
             {
                 .p_voertuigid = v.fk_type_voertuig,
                 .p_voertuigomschr = tv.type + " -- " + tv.merk
             }
```

I would like to group on `.p_voertuigid`. I already tried some options without any result. I hope someone here can help me.

Thanks in advance!

I think i am almost there, but now i'm getting a new exception:

```
Value of type system.collections.generic.list(of <anonymoustype>) cannot be converted
to system.collections.generic.list(of tbl_voertuig)
```

This is my new code

```
Dim result = (From v In dc.tbl_voertuigs
              Join tv In dc.tbl_type_voertuigs On tv.pk_type_voertuig Equals v.fk_type_voertuig
              Join tbc In dc.tbl_tebehalencertificaats On tbc.pk_tebehalencertificaat Equals v.fk_tebehalencertificaat
              Where tbc.naam_certificaat = subquery2
              Group By v = New Voertuig With
              {
                  .p_voertuigid = v.fk_type_voertuig,
                  .p_voertuigomschr = tv.type + " -- " + tv.merk
              } Into grp = Group).ToList
Return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, this is the final code and it works

```
        Dim result = From v In dc.tbl_voertuigs
                 Join tv In dc.tbl_type_voertuigs On tv.pk_type_voertuig Equals v.fk_type_voertuig
                 Join tbc In dc.tbl_tebehalencertificaats On tbc.pk_tebehalencertificaat Equals v.fk_tebehalencertificaat
                 Where tbc.naam_certificaat = subquery2
                 Group By v = New Voertuig With
                        {
                            .p_voertuigid = v.fk_type_voertuig,
                            .p_voertuigomschr = tv.type + " -- " + tv.merk
                        } Into grp = Group _
                Select v
    Return result.ToList
```

I hope this can help someone who has the same problem in the future

Grtz

Yannick